# How to define a pass-through (identity or NOP) macro?

Tags: macros, rust

When porting code from another language, I'd like to keep some expressions such as `likely`/`unlikely` macros as a *dummy* macro.

Example usage:

```
if expr_nop!(expression) { 
    code;
}
```

... which should be *exactly* the same as writing:

```
if (expression) { 
    code;
}
```

Whats a good fail-safe macro in rust that can be used as a no-op?

Currently I have:

```
macro_rules! expr_nop { ($body:expr) => { $body } }
```

Is this correct or should this be written differently?

Comment: Isn't it better to call this 'identity macro', by analogy with identity function? `no-op` in my opinions stands for literally doing nothing, not for leaving expression as is.

Comment: @deniss, you're probably right, am new to this terminology.

Comment: Relevant for your original issue: [Implement likely/unlikely intrinsic](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26179).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your macro ...

```
macro_rules! expr_nop { ($body:expr) => { $body } }
```

... is correct.

It does one thing, though:  It checks that the argument to the macro is actually an expression.  So e.g. `expr_nop(i32)` would give a compile-time error since i32 is a type and not an expression (which is often a good thing, since otherwise `if expr_nop!(i32) {...}` would give a compile-time error instead, and that error might be more complicated).

The error would be compile-time in both cases, but in the first case before (during) macro-expansion and in the second case after macro-expansion, which often makes it harder to link the error to the code you are trying to compile.